# connection refused -- Nginx to Python BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a simple Python web server from a tutorial on a Fedora box running Nginx; I want Nginx to reverse proxy the Python server. I must be doing something wrong, though, because when I run the server and attempt to load the page through Nginx, Nginx returns a 502 to the browser and prints the following to the log:

> 2017/03/16 00:27:59 [error] 10613#0: *5284 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   76.184.187.130, server: tspi.io, request: "GET /leaderboard/index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8063/leaderboard/index.html",
>   host: "tspi.io"

Here's my python server:

```
#!/bin/env python
# with special thanks to the good folks at
# https://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php
# who generous taught me how to do all this tonight

import cgi

from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep

class BaseServer (BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET (self):
        try:
            print ('Serving self.path=' + self.path)
            if 'leaderboard' in self.path:
                self.path = self.path[12:]
                print ('self.path amended to:' + self.path)

            if self.path == '/':
                self.path = '/index.html'

            if self.path.endswith ('.html'):
                # maybe TODO is wrap this in a file IO exception handler
                f_to_open = curdir + sep + self.path
                f = open (f_to_open)
                s = f.read()
                f.close()

                self.send_response (200)
                self.send_header ('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers ()
                self.wfile.write (s)

            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error (404, 'File Not Found: ' + self.path)

    def do_POST (self):
        try:
            cytpe, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader ('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                query=cgi.parse_multipart (self.rfile, pdict)
            self.send_response (301)

            self.endheaders()


        except:
            pass # What *do* you do canonically for a failed POST?

def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer (('', 8096), BaseServer)
        print ('Starting BaseServer.')
        server.serve_forever ()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('Interrupt recieved; closing server socket')
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tspi.io;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tspi.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        root /data/www;
    }

    location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
        root /data/images;
    }

    location /leaderboard {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8063;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the proxy_pass to pass any traffic that comes in to tspi.io/leaderboard on to the Python server, while allowing the base html pages that live under /data/www to be served by Nginx normally.

When I google, I see tons of stuff about reverse proxying PHP not having PHP-FPM configured correctly, and since I'm not using PHP at all that seems improbable. I also see stuff about configuring uwsgi, which I have no idea if that's an issue or not. I don't know if BaseHTTPServer uses uswgi; when I tried looking uswgi up, it seemed like a whole different set of classes and a whole other way to write a python server.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port numbers are mix-matched in your python code vs. what is provided in your nginx reverse proxy config.

I'd also recommend sending the host and remote address values to your internal application in case the need for them arises.

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also noticed that in addition to that typo, my python didn't properly handle the "leaderboard" prefix in the url path. Updated code in original post.